# Duplicate data in target synced S3 bucket after Spark job reload

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, replication, cloudera

Spark job on Cloudera cluster(CDH 6.3.3) writes Parquet file to s3bucket1 with options .write.mode("overwrite")
There is a Replication rule which syncs data from s3bucket1 to s3bucket2. Delete marker replication is Enabled in the rule.
If Spark Job is restarted several times the previous files left in target s3bucket2(in s3bucket1 everything is ok).
So finally there is duplicates data in s3bucket2.
Spark params related to S3 writer:

```
spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.multiobjectdelete.enable=false
```

If files deleted manually(via AWS console) from the source location s3bucket1 the replicated files also deleted well. But when Spark does this - the previous files left in the target s3bucket2 bucket.
It looks like Spark uses the wrong/obsolete API/approach for deleting objects on S3.

Comment: UPDATE:  the problem is not in Spark but in S3 permission  - from different Roles the behavior is different even if use CLI  command: AWS S3 RM <path>

Answer (score 0):

1. renable multi-object delete, as its way faster for bulk deletes
2. switch to the S3A committers, which CDH6.x does support and which are both fast and provide the correctness on s3 which the classic commit-by-rename committers lack
3. what do you mean by "replication rule"? Do you have something replicating the data (e.g. distcp?), or are you trying to do this in spark?

Comment: Replication rule - this is usual S3  functionality to setup automatic sync between the bucket.  I use with enabled option: Replication Time Control, Delete marker replication, Replication metrics and notifications.

Comment: The duplicates occurs in the target bucket(s3bucket2 in my description) not in source bucket(s3bucket1). Spark writes data to s3bucket1.  The special  case is that Spark located in a different account than buckets.  So now I have a test case which shows that problem not in Spark but in some S3 policies. If I delete files under the same account with bucket by AWS S3 RM command all works perfectly. But if I delete files under different account(where CDH located) the  delete marker didn’t replicate.

Comment: Maybe its related to the fact that IAM needs different permissions to work on versioned artifacts, or there's some other permission which is needed.